# Defining new function as a composition of functions while adding additional behaviours

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have started to solve the [99 problems in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10), and for the second question, it is given the following solution:

```
myButLast' :: [a] -> a
myButLast' = last . init
```

and if we give the empty list to this function, we get and error, however, I would like to print a specific error as

```
myButLast' [] = error "The list has to have at least 2 elements!"
myButLast' [x] = error "The list has to have at least 2 elements!"
```

but when I add these line to the code, I get

> Equations for ‘myButLast'’ have different numbers of arguments

, so is there a way to use the composition type of defining my new function while also adding some specific behaviour ?

Comment: No, in Haskell for all clauses, the number of parameters has to be the same.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for pointing out, but I can understand that from the given error. What I'm asking is that what kind of "trick" that I can use to achieve the thing that I'm trying.

Comment: if `a = (b . c)`, then also `a x = (b . c) x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do is probably something like the following, where the error checking is moved into an auxiliary function (which I've named `go` for lack of a better name) defined in a `where` clause:

```
myButLast :: [a] -> a
myButLast = go (last . init)

  where
    go _ []  = bad
    go _ [x] = bad
    go f xs  = f xs

    bad = error "The list has to have at least 2 elements!"
```

It might help make it clearer what's going on if we define `go` separately with a type signature.  Also, in case you find the underscores confusing, I've replaced them with `f`:

```
myButLast :: [a] -> a
myButLast = go (last . init)

go :: ([a] -> a) -> [a] -> a
go f []  = bad
go f [x] = bad
go f xs  = f xs

bad = error "The list has to have at least 2 elements!"
```

Here, you can see that `go` is a function that takes two arguments, the first being itself a **function** of type `[a] -> a` and the second being a list of type `[a]`.

The above definition of `go` pattern matches on the second argument (the list).  If the list is empty or a singleton, then the result of `go` is just `bad` (the error message), regardless of the function `f`.  Otherwise (if the list is at least two elements), the result of `go f xs` is simply to apply the first argument (that function `f`) to the list `xs`.

How does this work?  Well, let's see what happens if we apply `myButLast` to a list.  I've used the symbol "≡" here to show equivalence of Haskell expressions with comments explaining why they are equivalent:

```
myButLast [1,2,3]
-- by the definition of "myButLast"
≡ go (last . init) [1,2,3]
-- by the definition of "go", third pattern w/
--    f ≡ last . init
--    xs = [1,2,3]
≡ (last . init) [1,2,3]   -- this is just f xs w/ the pattern substitutions
-- because of your original, correct answer
≡ 2
```

If we apply it to a "bad" list, the only difference is the pattern matched from the definition of `go`:

```
myButLast [1]
-- by the definition of "myButLast"
≡ go (last . init) [1]
-- by the definition of "go", second pattern w/
--    f ≡ last . init
--    x = 1
≡ bad
-- gives an error message by definition of "bad"
```

As an interesting aside, another way to look at `go` is that it's a function:

```
go :: ([a] -> a) -> ([a] -> a)
```

Because the function application arrow `->` is right associative, this type signature is exactly the same as `([a] -> a) -> [a] -> a`.  The neat thing about this is that now it's clear that `go` takes a function of type `[a] -> a` (such as `last . init`) and returns another function of type `[a] -> a` (such as `myButLast`).   That is, `go` is a transformer that adds additional behavior to an existing function to create a new function, which is exactly what you were asking for in your original question.

In fact, if you slightly generalize the type signature so that `go` can operate on a function taking a list, regardless of what it returns:

```
go :: ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> b
go _ [] = bad
go _ [x] = bad
go f xs = f xs
```

this still works.  Then, you could use this **same** `go` on anything that needed a list of length two, whatever it returned.  For example, if you had an original implementation to return the last two elements of a list:

```
lastTwoElements :: [a] -> [a]
lastTwoElements = (!! 2) . reverse . tails   -- tails from Data.List
```

you could re-write it as:

```
lastTwoElements :: [a] -> [a]
lastTwoElements = go ((!! 2) . reverse . tails)
```

to add error handling for the empty and singleton list cases.

In this case, you'd probably want to rename `go` to `usingTwoElements` or `withList2` or something...

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer @Buhr. I'm new to Haskell, so is there any chance that you can explain your code from the second line to the end ? For example, I do not know what does `go` do, and what does the syntax `go f xs` means, etc.

Comment: @onurcanbektas `go` is defined above: it's just a name for an arbitrary function. You can replace each `go` above with `helperFunction` or any other name and achieve the same result.

Comment: what about `go f xs` ? what does this do ? Plus, why does `go` function takes two arguments ?

Comment: Ok, I have now understood why what does the code do. It is a pretty good method actually. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I added some additional explanation as well.

Comment: IMO, using the helper `go` here adds more complexity than it saves. Just define `init'` in terms of `init`, with the same three cases. Then `myButLast = last . init' where init' = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Use an explicit argument in the solution:

```
myButLast' x = last (init x)
```

Now you can add your special cases just above that line.

The original solution used a pointfree style `last . init` to avoid mentioning the `x` argument. However, if you have to add further equations, you need to make the argument explicit.

Moving from

```
fun :: A -> B
fun = something
```

to

```
fun :: A -> B
fun a = something a
```

is called eta-expansion, and is a common transformation of Haskell code. The first style is usually called point-free (or, jokingly, point-less), while the second one is called pointful. Here "point" refers to the variable `a`.

Comment: Actually, that is my original solution to the problem, but defining the `myButLast` function as a composition of other function is mathematically intriguing, and that is why I'm trying to learn how can I use the composition method while I'm not losing anything.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Would `myButLast' x = (last . init) x` still be acceptable to you? This style (using composition) does not always lead to simpler code -- sometimes it's better to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat sidestepping the original question, but you may be interested in the `safe` package for tasks like this. In general, you should strive to use total functions that don't raise errors. In this case, that means using something like `lastMay :: [a] -> Maybe a` and `initMay :: [a] -> Maybe a`, which simply return `Nothing` if given an empty list. They can be composed using `<=<`, found in `Control.Monad`.

```
import Safe

myButLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
myButLast = lastMay <=< initMay
```

Then

```
> myButLast []
Nothing
> myButLast [1]
Nothing
> myButLast [1,2]
Just 1
```

If you really want an error message, `Safe` provides `lastNote` and `initNote` as well.

```
myButLast = let msg = "Need at least 2 elements" in (lastNote msg . initNote msg)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @chepner, can I ask what does `Maybe` syntax do in general ? What is it purpose ?

Comment: A value of type `Maybe a` is either a value of type `a` wrapped in the `Just` constructor, or it is the absence of such a value, represented by `Nothing`. Compare `<=< :: (b -> Maybe c) -> (a -> Maybe b) -> a -> Maybe c` (specialized for `Maybe` here) with `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`; think of it as function composition where you need to unwrap the return value of the first function before passing it to the second function.

Answer (score 1):

You could often simply compose an additional function that has the additional behaviour:

```
myButLast' :: [a] -> a
myButLast' = last . init . assertAtLeastTwo
  where assertAtLeastTwo xs@(_:_:_) = xs
        assertAtLeastTwo _ = error "The list has to have at least 2 elements!"
```

Here we've added a function that checks for the conditions we want to raise an error, and otherwise simply returns its input so that the other functions can act on it exactly as if `assertAtLeastTwo` wasn't there.

Another alternative that allows you to clearly highlight the error conditions is:

```
myButLast' :: [a] -> a
myButLast' [] = error "The list has to have at least 2 elements!"
myButLast' [x] = error "The list has to have at least 2 elements!"    
myButLast' xs = go xs
  where go = last . init
```

Where you do the error checking as you originally wrote, but have the main definition simply defer to an implementation function `go`, which can then be defined point-free using composition.

Or you can of course inline `go` from above, and have:

```
myButLast' xs = (last . init) xs
```

Sine a composition of functions is itself an expression, and can simply be used in a larger expression directly as the function. In fact a fairly common style is in fact to write code of the form "compose a bunch of functions then apply to this argument" this way, using the `$` operator:

```
myButLast' xs = last . init $ xs
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would use wrappers you can have the best of both worlds and a clear separation between the two. Robust error checking and reporting and a vanilla function to use however you wish, with or without the wrapper.
Interesting, the vanilla function reports 'last' cannot process an empty list given a one element list and 'init' cannot process an empty list when given an empty list.

```
mbl2 = last . init
mbl xs = if length xs < 2 then error errmsg else mbl2 xs
    where errmsg = "Input list must contain at least two members."
```

Comment: That makes lots of sense @fpmore, thanks for your answer.